# Using Office Automation, export TextFrame shapes as Rtf

Tags: automation, export, powerpoint, rtf

I am writing an application the opens powerpoint presentations, finds a list of the shapes, and converts the contents of a TextFrame to Rtf. I easily can obtain the text from the TextFrame. The following code works great.

```
string strFilePath = @"i:\work\test1.pptx";

PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new PowerPoint.Application();
try
{
   PowerPoint_App.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
}
catch { }
PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;
PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(strFilePath, Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse);

for (int i = 0; i < presentation.Slides.Count; i++)
{
   foreach (PowerPoint.Shape shape in presentation.Slides[i + 1].Shapes)
   {
      switch (shape.Type)
      {
         case Office.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox:
            if (shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Length > 1)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("(x=" + shape.Left.ToString() + ", y=" + shape.Top.ToString() + ", 
                     w=" + shape.Width.ToString() + ", h=" + shape.Height.ToString() + ")\n" + 
                     shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text + "\n");
            }
            break;
      }
   }
}

PowerPoint_App.Quit();
```

But I need to get the contents of the TextFrame out as Rtf data. I  have tried the following:

```
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Copy();
string strRtfData = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

After this, though, the string is empty. What I would like is to have the Rtf data in the string.

Please let me know if you have clarification questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select something before copying it:

**Edit:** I guess this is the correct link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff746287%28v=office.14%29.aspx